# SPARQL: retrieve all the info from DBpedia from a URI

Tags: sparql, wikipedia, dbpedia

If I want to retrieve the abstract from a URI, I do the following:

```
PREFIX dbp_owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 

SELECT DISTINCT ?abstract WHERE { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Horizon_High_School_(Thornton,_Colorado)> dbp_owl:abstract ?abstract FILTER (lang(?abstract) = "en" )}
```

If I want to retrieve the thumbnail:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?thumb WHERE { <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Horizon_High_School_(Thornton,_Colorado)>  dbp_owl:thumbnail ?thumb }
```

How can I retrieve everything from the URI and not only one property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As to retrieving multiple properties, you can do that by using a variable in the property position.  E.g.,

```sql
select ?property ?value where {
  dbpedia:Mount_Monadnock ?property ?value
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20%3Fproperty%20%3Fvalue%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20dbpedia%3AMount_Monadnock%20%3Fproperty%20%3Fvalue%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Note that if you try to filter **?value** here by language, you'll miss a lot of results, because results that aren't literals, or aren't language tagged literals won't give you a value with the **lang** function.  So you really need restrict the filter a bit:

```sql
select ?property ?value where {
  dbpedia:Mount_Monadnock ?property ?value
  filter ( !isLiteral(?value)               #-- ?value is not a literal
        || lang(?value) = ""                #-- ?value is a non-language tagged literal
        || langMatches(lang(?value),"en"))  #-- ?value has a language tag matching "en"
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql/?default-graph-uri=http%3A%2F%2Fdbpedia.org&query=select%20%3Fproperty%20%3Fvalue%20where%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20dbpedia%3AMount_Monadnock%20%3Fproperty%20%3Fvalue%0D%0A%20%20filter%20%28%20!isLiteral%28%3Fvalue%29%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20%3Fvalue%20is%20not%20a%20literal%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7C%7C%20lang%28%3Fvalue%29%20%3D%20%22%22%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%23%20%3Fvalue%20is%20a%20non-language%20tagged%20literal%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7C%7C%20langMatches%28lang%28%3Fvalue%29%2C%22en%22%29%29%20%20%23%20%3Fvalue%20has%20a%20language%20tag%20matching%20%22en%22%0D%0A%7D&format=text%2Fhtml&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Note that you should not check languages with **=**, but with **langMatches** instead.  That will handle differences in capitalization, as well as a regional variants in language.